# SQL Server Connection Issue with New Router But Works With Old Router

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, router, local-area-network

I have an issue that really has me stumped.  I have a router that is overheating and needs to be upgraded.  When I connect the new router and configure it with the same DHCP settings and IP ranges as the old, everything on the network works fine, with the one exception being the SQL Server connection from all the clients on the LAN.

The connection just times out.  I can ping the server, access the file share on the server, remote desktop into the server, but running software that establishes a SQL connection times out.  The connection string is using the IP address, and all the SQL services are running normally.  I've enabled TCP/IP and named pipes in SQL Configuration Manager.

Actually I know the SQL Configuration is not the problem since all I'm doing to break and fix this issue is changing out the router. I can connect the old router back up and everything works fine.

Any idea what I need to look for?  I'm at a loss.

Comment: Some of this doesn't make sense. Local LAN traffic shouldn't transit the router. Is the router also a switch? Is the SQL server on the same subnet as the clients?

Comment: Sounds like something is blocking the ports - try a telnet session to the port SQL Server is listening on and see if it can connect. Is SQL Server getting the same IP address? Are you restarting the services after you change out the router?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and changing the **router firewall** to **low** or **disable it** solved the problem.